# How to merge two branches with some similar commits and no common ancestor?

Tags: git, merge, rebase

I have a repository with two branches, **master** and **front_end_dev**. One of my coworkers created the **front_end_dev** branch from **master** and they share a commit history, but the histories are separate and the branches are separated. Illustrated below:

```
MASTER            m1 -- m2 -- m3 -- m4 -- m5 -- m6 -- m7 -- m8 -- m9

FRONT_END_DEV     m1 -- m2 -- m3 -- m4 -- m5 -- f1 -- f2 -- f3 -- f4
```

For example, the first five commits are the same in both branches but then the histories diverge. However, the branches aren't connected by a single common ancestor. How would I go about either merging **front_end_dev** to **master** and/or rebasing **front_end_dev** so it properly branches off the last shared commit?

Comment: Option 1—On `MASTER`: `git merge FRONT_END_DEV` to create a merge commit where you'll have to reconcile conflicts (i.e. stuff from `m6` to `m9` not accounted for) or option 2—`FRONT_END_DEV`: `git rebase MASTER` to replay `f1` to `f4` on top of `m9`, which generates new commits (i.e. unsuitable if you want commits `f1` to `f4` to remain in history specifically). If you then follow 1) for `FRONT_END_DEV` now, it'll create a fast-forward merge (i.e. no merge commit, linear history).

Comment: Fantastic, that worked. Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From what I understand, commit `mi` on `master` has the same changes as commit `mi` on `front_end_dev` (i = 1, ..., 5), but they have a different hash since you say the histories are separate.

**rebase**

```
git checkout front_end_dev
git rebase master
```

This would rebase `front_end_dev` on `master`. You would have all those commits lined up on `front_end_dev` (`m1 - m9` followed by `m1 - m5 - f1 - f4`). Since the `mi` commits on both branches have the same changes, this rebase would generate a lot of conflicts. Once you get those painful conflicts resolved, you can then fast-forward on master:

```
git checkout master
git merge front_end_dev
```

**merge**

```
git checkout master
git merge front_end_dev
```

This is the easiest and maybe the best option. You simply generate a merge commit and resolve the conflicts.

**rebase f1-f4**

If you are really sure that commits `mi` (i = 1, ..., 5) contain the same changes on both branches, you might want to rebase only commits `f1-f4` onto master.

```
git checkout <hash-commit-f1> # checkout to commit f1
git checkout -b branch_with_fi # create a branch from commit f1
git merge frond_end_dev # add commits f2, f3 and f4 to the new branch
```

Now you can rebase or merge the new branch:

```
git rebase master
```

or

```
git checkout master
git merge branch_with_fi
```